# Merge [restricted-stock] and [rsu]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tags [restricted-stock](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-stock) and [rsu](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rsu) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree about merging and propose `rsu` as the merged tag because it's how the concept is often referred to.

EDIT:
Now done. I did pause briefly as there were 59 `restricted-stock` questions and only 7 `rsu` ones, but almost all of the 59 explicitly used the term "RSU", so I think my argument that it's the more common name still holds.